# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 - using @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I am trying to replicate the following [Cascading DropDowns tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/216632/cascading-dependent-dropdownlist-using-aspnet-mvc.html) in my .net core application. I am using a WebAPI for my controllers and services... however to simplify and more closely match the tutorial, I have moved the controller to the client. The logic in the Controller is very similar to that of the tutorial, and clearly it is working well enough to at least populate the dropdowns initially on page load.

I am struggling a bit with the Javascript (which I believe is the cause of the 400 error), and I using a semi-custom model framework that is about 90% based on the tutorial model. The crazy thing is that the Javascript is running (I believe) since it stops at the breakpoints in the JS code as it initially populates the 3 drop downs on page load correctly. However, once I select any item in any of the 3 dropdown controls... instead of calling the 'on change' event, it triggers the following error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () [https://localhost:44317/]**

I can provide more code if needed, but I have pasted below the crux of the logic that I believe is where the problem exists:

==== Index.cshtml code below ====

```
@page
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@model MTGCardTracker.Client.Pages.IndexModel
<div id="dropDownListdiv">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CascadingDropDownList", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CascadingDropDown.FormatId, Model.CascadingDropDown.Formats, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CascadingDropDown.EditionId, Model.CascadingDropDown.Editions, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CascadingDropDown.CardListId, Model.CascadingDropDown.Cards, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
                         $("#dropDownListdiv").on("change", "select", function () {
                               var value = $(this).val();
                               var id = $(this).attr("id");
                               $.post("@Url.Action("SetDropDrownList")", { type: id, value: value }, function (data) {
                                     switch (id) {
                                         case "FormatId":
                                             PopulateDropDown("#CascadingDropDown_EditionId", data.CascadingDropDown.Editions);
                                             PopulateDropDown("#CascadingDropDown_CardListId", data.CascadingDropDown.Cards);
                                                 break;
                                         case "EditionId":
                                             PopulateDropDown("#CascadingDropDown_CardListId", data.CascadingDropDown.Cards);
                                                 break;
                                      }
                             });
                         });
                     });
        function PopulateDropDown(dropDownId, list) {
            $(dropDownId).empty();
            $(dropDownId).append("<option>Please select</option>")
            $.each(list, function (index, row) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    $(dropDownId).append("<option value='" + row.Value + "' selected='selected'>" + row.Text + "</option>");
                } else {
                    $(dropDownId).append("<option value='" + row.Value + "'>" + row.Text + "</option>")
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Below is my model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MTGTracker.DTO
{
    public class CascadingDropDownDTO
    {
        public string FormatId { get; set; }
        public string EditionId { get; set; }
        public string CardListId { get; set; }
        public SelectList Formats { get; set; }
        public SelectList Editions { get; set; }
        public SelectList Cards { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<FormatDTO> FormatObject { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EditionDTO> EditionObject { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CardDetailDTO> CardObject { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Below (in _Layout.cshtm) is *I beleive* the only place I am referencing the JS and Boostrap files in my code now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MTGCardTracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>*@

    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">MTGCardTracker</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - MTGCardTracker - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>



    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

========== SetDropDownList ==========

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SetDropDrownList(string type, int value)
{
    CascadingDropDownDTO model = GetCascadingDropDownListObject(CascadingDropDown);

    switch (type)
    {
        case "FormatId":
        var EditionsList = CascadingDropDown.EditionObject.Where(m => m.FormatId == value).ToList();
        model.Editions = new SelectList(EditionsList, "EditionId", "EditionName");
        var defaultEditionId = EditionsList.Select(m => m.EditionId).FirstOrDefault();
        model.Cards = new SelectList(CascadingDropDown.CardObject.Where(m => m.EditionId == defaultEditionId).ToList(), "CardListId", "Name");
        break;
        case "EditionId":
        model.Cards = new SelectList(CascadingDropDown.CardObject.Where(m => m.EditionId == value).ToList(), "CardListId", "Name");
        break;
    }
    return Json(model);
}
```

Token shown in code below even after I removed the submit button. So it seems it is simply tied to the page and/or the dropdowns.

[image: Token is still there even with submit button removed.]

Below is the Post. Not sure if I can drill down further for more details as I am still fairly new to trying to debug JS in the browser:

[image]

Comment: maybe you can test it by putting the .js references in the head element, just under the .css references. I have encountered some issues with JQuery references at the end of a page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggstion. I moved them up to the head (and updated the code sample above to reflect it), and still get the same 400 errors whenever I attempt to change a dropdown. I am thinking it might be more that I am not properly referencing the dropdown object in my javascript code. But I don't know.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see SetDropDrownList action . Could you post it pls?

Comment: Updated the code to add the SetDropDownList method. If it was failing anwhere in the controller... shouldn't I at least get the code to break inside the controller while debugging? I put breakpoints at the start of every method in the controller... and nothing is ever called after the page is initially loaded.

Comment: Is there an antiforgery token added in the page? Then the Ajax POST command should have that token in its post statement or a 400 error wil be returned. https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. yes, there is an antiforgery token, although it appears to be tied to the submit button, which I do not press. I am trying to get the JS to fire when I change the value of any one of the 3 dropdowns. I have included a picture of the token now as well.

Comment: After more testing, I have confirmed that the values are reaching the script, however the script call to my controller is not working because the controller is not being found. I'm in the process of trying to figure out why the script can't see my controller.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the answer for me was a couple things, but the below piece was possibly the most crucial. I needed to add the line "endpoints.MapControllerRoute ..." to my Startup.cs configure() method:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "CascadingDropDownList", pattern: "{controller=CascadingDropDownList}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

This allowed my Controller to be seen.

I also needed to modify my JS to account for the control id name changes since I was using a semi-custom nested model class that differed from the tutorial, and changed the $.post call from an action to a URL with the controller name and method call:

```
<script>
    src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" >
        /*CODE FOR THE CASCADING DROP DOWNS*/
        $(function () {
            $("#dropDownListdiv").on("change", "select", function () {

                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var value = $(this).val();
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
                alert($(this).val());
                alert("Executing POST...");
                $.post('/CascadingDropDownList/SetDropDrownList', { type: id, value: value }, function (data) {
                    switch (id) {
                        case "cascadingDropDown_FormatId":
                            PopulateDropDown("#cascadingDropDown_EditionId", data.Editions);
                            PopulateDropDown("#cascadingDropDown_CardListId", data.Cards
                            break;
                        case "cascadingDropDown_EditionId":
                            PopulateDropDown("#cascadingDropDown_CardListId", data.Cards);
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
            alert("Exited Main Function");
        });

    function PopulateDropDown(dropDownId, list) {
        alert("Entered PopulateDropDown...");
        alert("dropDownId: " + dropDownId);
        $(dropDownId).empty();
        $(dropDownId).append("<option>Please select</option>")
        alert("Running ForEach...");
        $.each(list, function (index, row) {
            if (index == 0) {
                $(dropDownId).append("<option value='" + row.Value + "' selected='selected'>" + row.Text + "</option>");
            } else {
                $(dropDownId).append("<option value='" + row.Value + "'>" + row.Text + "</option>")
            }
        });
        alert("Exited PopulateDropDown...");
    }
</script>
```

Now my SetDropDownList method is being called correctly. And while my dropdowns are not being popoulated correctly, they are being reset to empty by the JS calls, so I know I am at least targeting them correctly. Figuring out why they aren't getting the correct new filtered subset list is next.

Hopefull this helps someone else. I think the main issue is my lack of familiarity with MVC vs Razor MVC and all the basic fundumentals and nuances that come with them.